# How to return an XML SQL data type from my stored procedure to PHP

Tags: php, xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have been trying to execute a stored procedure and return an XML data type for display through PHP.

Here is what I have - a simple stored procedure, getXML as follows:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[getXML] 
AS

select --some fields
from --some table
for XML auto, elements

GO
```

This statement works fine when I execute it through SQL Server Management Studio and outputs an XML result set.

How do I get that result set to display on the php page?

So far, I am able to do the following in PHP:

```
<?php

  $server = 'thisServer';
  // Connect to MSSQL
 $link = mssql_connect($server, 'user', 'pass');

  if (!$link) {

      die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');

  }


  // Create a new statement
  $stmt = mssql_init('dbo.getXML');


  // Execute the statement

  $result = mssql_execute($stmt);
  $count = mssql_num_rows($result);
  if($count == 0)
  {
    print "<p>No results</p>";
  }
  else
  {
    $row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result);
        foreach($row as $field => $value):
            $field
        endforeach;

    mssql_data_seek($result, 0);

    while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    foreach($row as $value):
        =$value
    endforeach;
    }

    mssql_free_statement($stmt);
?>
```

While I can get the result to print, it looks terrible... not like an XML output at all.

How can I get an XML output from my stored procedure into php?

I have tried: sqlsrv_get_field and SQLSRV_PHPTYPE_STREAM(SQLSRV_ENC_CHAR)) but I must have been using them incorrectly and am unable to get it to work.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @XML XML

SET @XML = (

SELECT something 
FROM sometable
FOR XML PATH('items'), ROOT('root')

)

SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @XML)
```